# Page_404_error (production error) when I trigger URL endpoint from postman to production server

Tags: c#, docker, logging, http-status-code-404

I am new to docker container. The "GET" request is working fine in local(even postman with local request). When I give the request from postman to production env, the docker container log seems not triggered. I don't know where the issue from and don't know how to debug the issue.
Any help on this issue. Thanks

1. Tried with URL endpoint.
2. Tried to trigger other containers, its working fine.
3. Tried with front end locally, Its working fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue was identified by Devops team and they solved. Thanks for your support.